# Java Swing making boxes with custom dimensions

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grid-layout, boxlayout

I need help making a layout in Java Swing. My boxes are coming out to be really small and can't figure out how to make them bigger.

Here is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/acRjl.png

[image]

And here is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoja3.png

[image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MPC
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
            createWindow();
    }

    public static void createWindow()
    {
            JPanel main, left, right;
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("MPC");
            Box [] box = new Box[16];
            JSlider tempo = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 30, 15);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            main = new JPanel();
            main.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

            //Left side holds boxes
            left = new JPanel();
            left.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

            for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                    box[i] = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
                    box[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                    box[i].add(new JLabel("      " + (i+1) + "      "));
                    left.add(box[i]);
            }

            //Right side for tempo
            right = new JPanel();
            right.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            tempo.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
            tempo.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
            tempo.setPaintTicks(true);
            right.add(tempo);

            //Add everything to window
            main.add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
            main.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);

            frame.add(main);
            frame.getContentPane();

            //Window Stuff
            frame.setBounds(50,50,500,500);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What can I do to make it look like the second picture? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the layout of `main` to `BorderLayout`:

```
main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Then, add add `left` panel to the center of `BorderLayout`

```
main.add(left, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This way the grid of boxes will occupy as much of the available space of `main` as possible. See [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details.

Result with these changes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

+1 for @Aqua, plus a few (more than important) enhancements

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class MPC {

    private JPanel main, left, right;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("MPC");
    private JSlider tempo = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 30, 15);

    public MPC() {
        left = new JPanel();
        left.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1));
            left.add(panel);
        }

        tempo.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        tempo.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        tempo.setPaintTicks(true);

        right = new JPanel();
        right.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 50, 20, 20));
        right.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 1));
        right.add(tempo);

        main = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 300);
            }
        };
        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        main.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        main.add(left, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        main.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.add(main);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MPC();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for improving it! Learned a lot from it.